# mysql 'show create table' on several tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have to get the `SHOW CREATE TABLE tblName` output of all the tables and write it to  files (one file for each table).

Anyone can help me how I can begin to this? I suppose stored procedures? I am pretty sure that there is a tutorial I can follow because MySQL has a big community..

Thanks in advance

Some pictures of the output I need of each table:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9x2ek.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jIEJ.png]

Comment: I don't know what `mysqldump` is but I mean: http://screencast.com/t/slh6TunP2 I need to save this output to a file for each table. The written files can be of any extension I only need to read it with a programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your screenshot shows that you're using Windows; you can use [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) for your task.

There's an option in tools, titled **Export database as SQL**.

Comment: Thank you so much, I already have the files created. That was fast.

Comment: You know how you should do this in a Linux environment? Because we work also in a Linux environment

Comment: For linux, the commands will be displayed in the status box inside HeidiSQL. Otherwise, read about `mysqldump`.

Comment: HeidiSQL will run in a linux or OSX environment via WINE